# GotoMeeting Webinar prospects are not syncing to Pardot

Tags: pardot

I have created 14 days free trail account for GoToMeeting Webinar.
Added connector in Salesforce Pardot successfully.
Scheduled Webinar on GoToWebinar it got sync with Pardot Calendar.
But when I registered for GoToWebinar and expecting Prospect to sync in Pardot it was not there.

Not sure where to look for this sync issue.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It took bit longer for first time sync.
And after couple of hours I could see the prospect with proper score there in Pardot.